# How to build a solid css font stack for emoji?

Tags: css, fonts, emoji

I'm using Symbola as a web font for showing emoji in a website.
I [downloaded Symoba from here](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) and converted the .ttf to a woff.

My font stack looks like this:

```
.inner-message{
  font-family: 'open_sanslight', 'symbola', 'helvetica neue', 'arial', sans-serif;
}
```

I'd like to explicitly target the emoji fonts in iOS and Android as part of this css.
These look more attractive than Symobla, as they offer a mixture of colours.
Something like:

```
.inner-message{
  font-family: 'open_sanslight', 'iOS emoji', 'android emoji', 'symbola', 'helvetica neue', 'arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Where real names are used for the iOS and Android emoji fonts. What is the css rule I need to write so I can explicitly target the fonts I want?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688046/css-reference-to-phones-emoji-font

Answer (score 2):

The real font is **AppleColorEmoji.ttf** or **Apple Color Emoji.ttf**. And of Android emoji is **NotoEmoji.ttf** or **NotoColorEmoji.ttf** (Android 4.3 and later) and **AndroidEmoji.ttf** (Android 3 and later).

Comment: Is it possible to directly reference those fonts in CSS?

Comment: I don't know. Try for yourself: Add @font-face and put the emoji font name and add the same emoji font name to the tag body.

Comment: I've tried several variants in the font-face - `NotoEmoji`, `Noto Emoji`, etc. None seem to work. :sad face:

Comment: The emoji font added to the tag body or to other tag on HTML or CSS file, works only OS X 10.7x, iOS 6x, Windows 8.1, and on Android 4.4x. You won't see the emojis on the old versions of OSes.